# dragPreviewRender doesn't work on RTL pages

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, treeview, register-transfer-level

minop1205/react-dnd-treeview is a draggable / droppable React-based treeview component. When you drag a node and expect to see its preview on RTL pages, *dragPreviewRender* in **React DnD TreeView** component doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix it in:

> node_modules@minoru\react-dnd-treeview\dist\index.js

on line **835**:

```
var x = offset.x, y = offset.y;
```

and change it to:

```
var x = offset.x - window.innerWidth, y = offset.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by using absolute positioning:

```js
<Tree
    ...
    dragPreviewRender={(monitorProps) => (
      <div style={{
          zIndex: 9999,
          maxWidth: 'max-content',
          position: 'absolute',
          left: 0,
        }}>
      {monitorProps.item.text}
      </div>
    )}
    ....
/>
```

This causes the preview element to come out of the flow and gives us more control over its position. By using `left: 0` we will override the position that was previously set by the library and cause it to show properly on RTL websites.